# Password Confirmation field is not working in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

```
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label control-label-1">Password</label>
                                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-1" ng-model="Userdata.password" required="">

                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-xs-6">  

                                            <div class="form-group"> 
                                                <label class="control-label control-label-1">Retype Password</label>
                                                <input type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" name="password2" class="form-control form-control-1" ng-model="Userdata.password2" required="">
                                               <div ng-show="Userdata.password != Userdata.password2">Password mis match!</div>

                                            </div>  

                                        </div>
```

password and password confirmation field is not working properly,error message is displaying before entering the confirm field, that is when the password field entering itself. 
how can i make the code properly.

Comment: When are you expecting to show the error?? once user has done entering the second password or while user is entering sencond password?

Answer (score 2):

Add AND condition in your ng-show,

```
<div ng-show="(Userdata.password && Userdata.password2 && (Userdata.password != Userdata.password2))">Password mis match!</div>
```